# Would executing the below given code will delete all the previous data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What if some data is already there inside the `users` collection ? 
Would doing this  will delete all the previous data ?

```
var messageRef = db.collection('users').doc(userID)
                .collection('private_user_data').doc(userID);
```

I want to add new data inside `users` collection and inside that a `doc` with 4 fields and one more `collection` inside that and inside that a `doc` with four more fields.

Comment: are you using realtime-database or firestore?

Comment: What do you mean through "will delete all the previous data?"?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I'm using firestone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question doesn't read from or write to the database in any way. It merely sets up a reference to a document in the database.

There are few ways to implement this, depending on your exact use-case:

- To merge data with an existing document, use the [`update` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).
- If the document may or may not exist, you can tell Firestore to *merge* the new values with the existing data when you call the [`set` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).
- If you want to set some fields only if the document doesn't exist yet, and leave them unmodified if the document already exists, you will need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). In that case you may also want to make sure your security rules reject modifications to those initial fields.

Answer (score 1):

With your code you don't make any operation on your db.

If you would know use `.set(someData)` your document would be created with given data if there is no document with given id or the document would be overwritten with the given data if there is a document with the given id.

Please check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) post from the Firebase docs for more information.

**EDIT**

To create a document you have to do something like this:

```
var messageRef = db.collection('users').doc(userID)
                .collection('private_user_data').doc(userID);

messageRef.set({
field1: input1,
field2: input2,
field3: input3,
field4: input4
})
```

Be aware that `messageRef.set()` will return a promise. So you have to deal with it. And here I would recommend you one of the tutorials from the Firebase team or one of many from the Internet.

Comment: I want to add new data inside `users` collection(this collection already exists) and inside that a `doc` with 4 fields and one more `collection` inside that and inside that a `doc` with four more fields.
So could you please send me the code for that ?

Comment: @Kundan I edited my post. But I highly recommend that you look up some tutorials from the internet. There are some really good explained ones and you will learn more by doing it yourself.